# fdisk (Linux) partitioning RAID 0

Tags: linux, raid, partitioning, slackware, fdisk

I'm trying to create partitions for a Slackware installation on my computer (beside Windows 7) just to have a nice distribution running mostly for school but when I run fdisk and print the partition table I get the following message:

> Partition x does not end on cylinder boundary.

(In my case x = 1, just using x to help googlers.)

I must say I'm using a RAID card (AMCC 3ware 9500S SATA RAID Controller). Maybe this is the problem.

How can I fix this without losing any data?

Comment: is this a real RAID card or a fakeRAID?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have a problem.

If your partitioning tool is seeing the RAID array properly, the RAIDness of the disk being partitioned doesn't matter.

I have heard that the actual layout of a modern disk is nothing like what is reported in the partitioning tool - so what is seen as a cylinder boundary in the partitioning tool probably isn't one anyway. The warning is just there for historical reasons.

The reason for the warning stems from the fact that MS-DOS (I think, but may be wrong - it hasn't been very relevant for ages) needed partitions that started and ended on a cylinder boundary. Windows carried on the tradition of making sure that partitions started ended on a cylinder boundary for no reason, externally created partitions that didn't end on the boundary worked ok.